How to connect from my host system to a Spark Container?
I have a container running Spark on port 7077 and got the container IP Address through the Docker inspect command, I'm trying to create a SparkSession through my host machine (I'm using Jupyter on my host) on the container's cluster.
I tried the following
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("spark://1.2.0.4:7077")
    .getOrCreate()
)

But it didn't work, and I got the error:

An error occurred while calling o24.conf.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LiveListenerBus is stopped.

I also tried using:
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077")
    .getOrCreate()
)

But, I got the same error.

You can bind the Spark container to the host network to avoid some errors, e.g. docker run -d --name spark-master --network host spark-image

Are you able to access the Spark UI at port 8080?
